# How to model heat movement and loss of a house?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, thermal-conductivity, building-physics

I was recently looking at the recommended insulation values for houses, and was surprised to find wall insulation recommendation was not just moderately less than the attic, but a tiny fraction of it. I am thinking that this probably has more to do with the amount of room available in the typical wall than the physics of thermal conductivity.

Has anyone done any work at modeling how heat moves in a house, any theory, or real world measurements or exactly what percentage of heat escapes from the roof vs walls?

Comment: Heat really likes to rise.

Comment: Hot air likes to rise - heat wil just flow from hot to cold, whatever direction that is.

Comment: Probably covered in engineering SE

Comment: @Nick Hot fluid with a typical density-temperature curve, if we really want to get pedantic.

Comment: Not sure about your house, but where I live the largest utility load is in the summer for air conditioning. The sun hits all of the roof (flat roof) all of the day. The walls are a much smaller total area, and are not all directly hit by the sun. So, insulating the roof is the first priority. And, making it white makes a big difference.

Comment: Generally roofs are made of a thin layer of slate or something, while walls are made of a thick layer of brick.

Comment: @JonCuster The same logic works for losing heat through natural convection in the winter in areas where the biggest load is your heating load.

Comment: @JMac - understood, just easier to make the point with the heating bit (at least to me - your mileage may vary).

Comment: There are practical constraints to consider when installing insulation.  Exterior walls are probably constructed from 2x4 studs, which leave a gap of 3.5 inches to install insulation in the walls.  On the other hand, attic ceilings are generally left "open" on the attic side of the ceiling, which allows for somewhat more than 3.5 inches of insulation, depending on the desires of the home owner.